# Use the localizedTitle key inPHoto framework fetchMomentsWithOptions query

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, photos, phasset

I want to filter out all moments which don't have a localizedTitle in iOS8. For this, I am using the Photo framework and the localizedTitle key. However this key doesn't seem to be working at all as an option in fetchMomentsWithOptions. Indeed, if I try the following:

```
    var collectionOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    collectionOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "!(SELF.localizedTitle = nil)")
    collectionOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "endDate", ascending: false)]
    self.fetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchMomentsWithOptions(collectionOptions) as PHFetchResult
```

it returns no event and if I do

```
    var collectionOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    collectionOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.localizedTitle = nil")
    collectionOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "endDate", ascending: false)]
    self.fetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchMomentsWithOptions(collectionOptions) as PHFetchResult
```

this fetch result returns all the moments in the photo library. As anyone come across the same problem